# Simplification imaginary fractions

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

In an exercise, a partial fraction expansion has to be done. I have no problem with that, but one of the last steps includes a simplification as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\left( -\frac 12 - \frac 16 i \right) \left(\frac{1}{s+1+3i}\right) +\left( -\frac 12 +\frac 16 i \right) \left(\frac{1}{s+1-3i}\right) \\
= -\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+3^2}-\frac 13\left( \frac{3}{(s+1)^2+3^2} \right).
\end{equation*}

My problem is that I do not understand the steps in between these two results. Could anyone explain how this is done? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @MarioG What do you mean with an extra sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is usually to realify(?) the denominators of your complex fraction. To do this, multiply the first term on the LHS by $1=\frac{s+1−3i}{s+1−3i}$. Multiply the second by $1=\frac{s+1+3i}{s+1+3i}$. These are just the complex conjugates of the denominators. Also, once you obtain the RHS, notice that you can simplify it further.  So let's try:

$$\left( -\frac 12 - \frac 16 i \right) \left(\frac{1}{s+1+3i}\right) +\left( -\frac 12 +\frac 16 i \right) \left(\frac{1}{s+1-3i}\right) \\
= -\frac 16\left(\frac{3+i}{s+1+3i}\right) +\frac 16\left(\frac{-3+i}{s+1-3i}\right) \\
= -\frac 16\left(\frac{3+i}{s+1+3i}\right)\left(\frac{s+1-3i}{s+1-3i}\right) +\frac 16\left(\frac{-3+i}{s+1-3i}\right)\left(\frac{s+1+3i}{s+1+3i}\right) \\ 
= -\frac 16\left(\frac{[3(s+1)+3]+[-9+(s+1)]i}{(s+1)^2+3^2}\right) +\frac 16\left(\frac{[-3(s+1)-3]+[-9+(s+1)]i}{(s+1)^2+3^2}\right) \\
= \left(\frac {-(s+1)-1}{(s+1)^2+3^2}\right) \\
= -\left(\frac {s+2}{(s+1)^2+3^2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! I just worked out your whole example myself and now I get it! The first step was the biggest problem, taking out the $ \frac 16 $. Again, thank you!